# Parent/child table with include/exclude items

Tags: postgresql, recursion, recursive-query

I have a table with parent-child relations. The relations can go n-level deep.
There is also a table with elements that belong to a group.

```
CREATE TABLE group_children(
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_id integer,
  children_id integer,
  contains boolean
);

CREATE TABLE group_item(
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  group_id integer,
  name text
);

INSERT INTO group_children(parent_id, children_id, contains) VALUES
  (1, 2, true),
  (1, 3, false),
  (2, 4, true),
  (2, 5, false),
  (3, 6, true),
  (3, 7, false);

INSERT INTO group_item(group_id, name) VALUES
  (4, 'aaa'),
  (4, 'bbb'),
  (5, 'bbb'),
  (5, 'ccc'),
  (6, 'aaa'),
  (6, 'bbb'),
  (7, 'aaa'),
  (7, 'ccc');
```

So, we can represent this data as [image]
It is not necessary to be in the form of a binary tree, just a simple case. Group can contains m child.

Need to read right to left. Group 4 contains ['aaa', 'bbb'], group 5 - ['bbb', 'ccc']. Group 2 includes all items from group 4 and excludes from group 5. So group 2 contains ['aaa']. And so on. After all computation group 1 will contain ['aaa'].

Question is: how to build a sql query to get all items that belong to the group 1?

All i could do:

```
WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
    SELECT group_children.parent_id, group_children.children_id, group_children.contains, group_item.name
    FROM group_children
    LEFT JOIN group_item ON group_children.children_id = group_item.group_id
    WHERE parent_id = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT group_children.parent_id, group_children.children_id, group_children.contains, group_item.name
    FROM group_children
    LEFT JOIN group_item ON group_children.children_id = group_item.group_id
    JOIN r ON group_children.parent_id = r.children_id
)
SELECT * FROM r;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e5e59/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=42963765afd1c7a9b4c6cac029542a33)

```
WITH RECURSIVE items AS (
    SELECT                -- 1
        group_id,
        array_agg(name)
    FROM 
        group_Item
    GROUP BY group_id

    UNION

    SELECT DISTINCT 
        parent_id, 
        array_agg(unnest) FILTER (WHERE bool_and) OVER (PARTITION BY parent_id) -- 5
    FROM (
        SELECT 
           parent_id,
           unnest,
           bool_and(contains) OVER (PARTITION BY parent_id, unnest) -- 4
        FROM items i 
        JOIN group_children gc           -- 2
        ON i.group_id = gc.children_id,
        unnest(array_agg)                -- 3
    ) s
)
SELECT * FROM items
```

1. The non-recursive part aggregates all names per `group_id`
2. Recursive part: Joining the chilren against their parents
3. Expanding the name arrays into one element per row.

This results in:

```
| group_id | array_agg | id | parent_id | children_id | contains | unnest |
|----------|-----------|----|-----------|-------------|----------|--------|
|        4 | {aaa,bbb} |  3 |         2 |           4 | true     | aaa    |
|        4 | {aaa,bbb} |  3 |         2 |           4 | true     | bbb    |
|        5 | {bbb,ccc} |  4 |         2 |           5 | false    | bbb    |
|        5 | {bbb,ccc} |  4 |         2 |           5 | false    | ccc    |
|        6 | {aaa,bbb} |  5 |         3 |           6 | true     | aaa    |
|        6 | {aaa,bbb} |  5 |         3 |           6 | true     | bbb    |
|        7 | {aaa,ccc} |  6 |         3 |           7 | false    | aaa    |
|        7 | {aaa,ccc} |  6 |         3 |           7 | false    | ccc    |
```

4. Now you have the unnested names. Now you want to find the ones that have to be excluded. Taking the bbb element for the `parent_id = 2`: There is one row with `contains = true` and one with `contains = false`. This should be excluded. Therefore all the names per `parent_id` have to be grouped. The contains values can be aggregated with boolean operators. The aggregate function `bool_and` gives only `true` if all elements are `true`. So `bbb` would get a `false` (The aggregation needs to be done as a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) because `GROUP BY` is not allowed within the recursive part for some reasons):

Result:

```
| parent_id | unnest | bool_and |
|-----------|--------|----------|
|         2 | aaa    | true     |
|         2 | bbb    | false    |
|         2 | bbb    | false    |
|         2 | ccc    | false    |
|         3 | aaa    | false    |
|         3 | aaa    | false    |
|         3 | bbb    | true     |
|         3 | ccc    | false    |
```

5. After that the unnested names can be grouped per `parent_id`. The `FILTER` clause only aggregates the elements where the `bool_and` is `true`. Of course you need to do this in a window function again. This creates duplicate records which can be removed by the `DISTINCT` clause

Final result (which of course could be filtered by the element `1`):

```
| group_id | array_agg |
|----------|-----------|
|        5 | {bbb,ccc} |
|        4 | {aaa,bbb} |
|        6 | {aaa,bbb} |
|        7 | {aaa,ccc} |
|        2 | {aaa}     |
|        3 | {bbb}     |
|        1 | {aaa}     |
```